# PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_cache_get() in /var/www/vhosts/visisite.com/httpdocs/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1367

Tags: ftp

Essentially all I did was to FTP the web files from BlueHost to XMission web server and plop them into the directory that looked like where they should go. I must have got the right directory because otherwise I don’t think there’d be anything there to throw an undefined function.

Let me know if there’s anything more you need from me and thanks for your help!

Frankly, this is out of my league so I’m hoping it will make some sense to you.

Comment: Does your ftp filter out files with "cache" in the name by any chance?

Comment: It shouldn't, it was just a straight copy of all the site's content

Comment: some core file wasn't uploaded properly or you have some misconfiguration. It is impossible to answer such a question without access to the server

Comment: Do you have any suggestions of where to look or what action to take?

Answer (score 2):

The [`wp_cache_get()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_cache_get/) function is part of wp-includes/cache.php file.

#### Check that cache.php exists

Please make sure that you have a `cache.php` file inside your `wp-includes/` folder. File: `wp-includes/cache.php`

#### Next step?

If the file does not exist, your installation of WordPress may be corrupt. You'll need to upload the missing files even manually by first downloading the latest [WordPress](https://wordpress.org/download/) version and ftping the missing files.

#### If the `cache.php` file exists

Download it and open it with any text editor on your device. Then please look for this function

#### `wp_cache_get()`

If you can't find this function, then please proceed with previous step.

If you can find this function, then somehow the function is blocked, in this case you'll have to contact your webhost or system administrator to get it sorted.

To read more about this function, where it is placed, and what does it do please refer to the codex here:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_cache_get/